# Where is the appropriate spot to seed and login a default user with ASP.NET MVC Identity 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, startup, asp.net-identity-2

I have an application that uses Identity 2.0 with Owin.

I want the application to seed a default user and log in automatically while on development (I'm wrapping the method and its call with `#if DEBUG` condition).

I tried adding the following method to *IdentityConfig.cs*`ApplicationUserManager.Create` method , but after calling it, `HttpContext.Current.User` is still null at the next call.

```
private void SeedAndLoginDefaultUser()
{
  var user = this.FindByName("***");
  if (user == null)
    this.Create(new ApplicationUser { /* ... */ }, "***");

  using (var signInManager = new ApplicationSignInManager(this, 
      HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication))
    signInManager.PasswordSignIn(user.UserName, "***", true, false);
}
```

But it keeps on authenticating the user over and over. I'm sure there should be a more appropriate location to perform this automation.
P.S. doing it from the *Global.asax.cs* or *Startup.cs* is impossible, since owin isn't initialized yet at that stage.

I tried adding it in the the Context initializer, the user gets created, but the login fails.

### Update

on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29133560/75500) answer:

Actually the UserManager is anyway overridden in the *IdentityConfig.cs* class. But what I'm thinking is, your solution will check for user existence each time a method attributed under `CustomAuthorize` is called. Whereas I only want to perform the default user creation and login only at app startup.

### Update 2

In my database initializer I have some crucial seed tables, that has data related to user, which means, I have to create the user in the seed method. So my question is now, when I create a user manually as the following code:

```
public class Initializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>
{
  private static volatile bool processing;
  protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
  {
    if (processing)
      return;
    processing = true;
    using (var um = ApplicationUserManager.Get())
    {
      var shimmy = new ApplicationUser
       {
         //Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
         FirstName = "Shimmy",
         LastName = "Weitzhandler",
         UserName = "***",
         Email = "***",
         //EmailConfirmed = true,
       };
      var task = um.CreateAsync(shimmy, "***");
      task.Wait();
      var result = task.Result;

      if (result.Succeeded)
      {
        using (var sm = ApplicationSignInManager.Get())
        {
          var siTask = sm.SignInAsync(shimmy, true, true);
          siTask.Wait();
          if (siTask.Exception != null)
          {
            throw siTask.Exception;
          }
        }
      }
      else
      {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
      }
    }

    //seed my tables
    processing = false;
  }
}
```

As you can see I even added a static member to avoid looping back the initializer, but I believe it still doesn't help.
Because when I'm trying to create the user manually (adding to the `Users` table, using the `UserManager.PasswordHasher`, I then can't log in to the account.
But the problem with the code above is that I'm calling it from the `Seed`, and I suspect it calls itself back internally when I try to create a user, then it gets stuck.
The resolution I'm looking for is how to create a user manually and be able to login to that account. I'm probably missing some point in the password hashing / user verification / whatever else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to this before the default Autorization starts. To do this the easiest way is to create your own AuthorizeAttribute.

```
public class MyCustomAuthorizeAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
{
   protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   {
      #if DEBUG
        return true;
      #else

      return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
   }

   public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
   {
      #if DEBUG
      // CHANGE TO YOUR USER MANAGER
      var userManger = filterContext.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUser>();

      var user = userManger.FindByName("***");
      if (user == null)
         this.Create(new ApplicationUser {/* ... */}, "***");

      using(var signInManager = new ApplicationSignInManager(userManger, filterContext.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication))
         signInManager.PasswordSignIn(user.UserName, "***", true, false);

      return;
      #endif

      return base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
   }
}
```

And then replace all existing **Authorize** attributes with your own, i.e.

```
[MyCustomAuthorize]

[MyCustomAuthorize(Roles = "ROLENAME")]
```

Solution 2:

If don't want do signin for each request, you can skip that but you still need to fetch the user from DB. Implement your service to getUser. Otherwise you can just hard code a user with a name and a role (if necessary).

```
public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    #if DEBUG
    // CHANGE TO YOUR USER MANAGER
    var user = GETUSER("");
    var principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(user.Name), new[] { user.RoleName });

    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
    HttpContext.Current.User = principal;

    return;
    #endif

    return base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
}
```

Comment: Looks nice, but is there a way to penetrate into the existing authorization process? I don't want to change all the `Authorize` attributes now.

Comment: You will only override the existing authorization when you are running the application in DEBUG mode. When you publish your application in RELEASE mode it will be running the default authorization.

Comment: Yeah I understood that, my question is if there is a way to achieve it without attributing all my controllers with a custom attributes, maybe by overriding the authorization user manager etc.?

Comment: I prefer to override the Authorize attrbiute over overriding the UserManager. Overriding the attribute is easy to change, debug and maintain.

Comment: Create user in DbContext Seed method

Comment: I tried that already. I used the password hash from the `UserManager.PasswordHasher`, but when I try to login I get an error that the login information is invalid.

Comment: The input password should not be hashed when sent to signInManager

Comment: You need to verify the user for each request. And that what's ASP.Identity is doing for you.

Comment: OK, you're right about the sign-in, but I have an issue with the seeding. Please see my updated question.

Comment: You shouldn't call the signInManger in seed. And if you are using Solution 2 you don't need to call the SignIn at all.

Comment: I want to use sln 1 of that link, but I don't how to hash password. User is created but login fails

Comment: I can't understand why it's neccesary for you in development "faking" the login process and then after all sign in anyway. I should go for solution 2, easier to implement and maintain. And with solution 2, you don't need a lot of code to handle your "faking login procedure during development". You will achieve the same thing with Solution 2 as with Solution 1.

Comment: I explained to you why I need it. I don't mind not logging in. I just need to add a valid user at database initialization. Problem is I don't know how to make password properly. I guess I'll add the password later.

Comment: I didn't understand sln 2

Comment: To get solution 2 to work you can skip the getUser part and just hard code any name the creation of GenericIdentity.

Comment: I want to be able to know if user is already signed in, and if he is, skip authorization, and HttpContext.User is always null for each request.